# Trying to create cleaner sql syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
select * from table
where in ('completedDate', 'completedBy', 'cancelDate', 'cancelBy') is not null
```

If the four columns above are not null I need to display the records.  I know I would do this with several where/and clauses but trying to learn and make my new stuff cleaner.

Is what I am trying to do above possible in a cleaner way?

Comment: That might be cleaner but it is wrong.  "in" is for values not columns.   e.g. releaseDate in ('1/1/2012','1/2/2012/')

Comment: I guess I should have explained the above code doesn't work.  It always returns 0 results.  Is there a way to do what I am trying to do above and have it work, without having 3+ where/and clauses? @Blam

Comment: @Blam: off-topic but "IN" works for columns as well and is sometimes surprisingly useful. I mean this kind of stuff: 'test' in (col1, col2)

Comment: 4 clauses in the where is only way I know to do it and I think it is clean.

Comment: If you are worried about number of lines in the select you you are worried about the wrong thing.  Is the select correct and is it efficient is what you should be focused on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly I guess you want to do that:

```
select * 
from table
where completedDate is not null
  and completedBy is not null
  and cancelDate is not null 
  and cancelBy is not null
```

Regarding clarity of code I don't see a better way to write it, that's what I would code anyway.

**EDIT**: I wouldn't really do that in this case, but if this is a very common condition you can add a computed column in the table (stored or not), or create a view on top of table, and do:

```
select * from view where importantFieldsAreNotNull = 1
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I had, was just hoping there was a more compact way of doing it either through using `IN` or `HAVING` because if I need to check many conditions I can see this getting to be pretty fat.

Comment: Yes, fat but still clear. If you have to check some conditions they gotta be written out somewhere. In my book simple and explicit (which this is) is better than clever and obscure. Note that I edited the solution: if you have some conditions that are logically tied together you _may_ want to merge them into one single check by hiding the logic in a view or a computed column.

Answer (score 2):

To Check if all Columns are not null:

```
  select * from table 
  where completedDate is not null
  and completedBy is not null
  and cancelDate is not null 
  and cancelBy is not null
```

Comment: Is adding 1 `where` and 3 `and` clauses the only way to do this?

Comment: The column names are `completedDate`, `completedBy` etc.  Is it possible to return all data from the table but do not return a row if the 4 columns contain a null value?

Comment: AFAIK: the easiest way to do this is really with one where and 3 ands

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, drats.  Was hoping I could condense it some.  Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: No worries. In a program you could easily build this query with iterations. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to return records where all four columns are not null?

The standard and (in my opinion) most readable way to do this would be:

```
Select
    *
From
    YourTable
Where
    Column1 IS NOT NULL AND
    Column2 IS NOT NULL AND
    Column3 IS NOT NULL AND
    Column4 IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to determine if all the column values were NULL.

The COALESCE function takes between 1 or more arguments and returns the first non-null argument. If at least one of the arguments passed into COALESCE is NOT NULL, then it will return that value, otherwise if all the arguments are NULL it returns NULL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE COALESCE(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) IS NOT NULL
```

Also depending on the datatypes of the columns, you may have to CAST them to the same datatype. For example, I wasn't able to use the COALECSE function on a DateTime column and a CHAR column without casting.

However, even though this would be shorter, I would not consider it "cleaner". I'd think it would be harder to read and maintain compared to having multiple ANDs in the WHERE clause.

Comment: But you need to CAST values and this is NOT shorter than Col1 IS NULL AND col2....

Comment: @Tomasito I forgot that all the columns need to be the same datatype for this to work. I'll update the answer. However, I'm not sure what you mean it's not shorter. Technically there's fewer characters if you want to check two more columns. But either way, I don't think this is a good solution, it's just what the OP was asking for.

Comment: `COALESCE(CAST(col1 as VARCHAR), CAST(col2 as VARCHAR) IS NOT NULL` is harder to read than `col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL`. It's shorter time to look at 2nd `WHERE` condition and understood it.

Comment: @Tomasito It may not be necessary to cast all the arguments to VARCHAR. It depends on the datatypes of the arguments to the function. I agree with you that this is not a very good solution, and I did state in my answer that it would be harder to read and maintain. However, this is what the OP asked for. Sometimes I think it's good to give a person what they've asked for, so that they can see for themselves that their desired solution really isn't as good as they think.

Comment: @AdamPorad Thanks Adam, I understand what you did and the point was well received.  You're right sometimes I need to see the wrong way to understand why the right way is better. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Under reasonable assumption on data types:
select *
from [table]
where completedBy+cancelBy+DATENAME(yy,completedDate)+ DATENAME(yy,cancelDate) 
is not null
```

Comment: This is brilliant!  Currently playing around with this to see if I can break it, but so far it's working perfectly.  Not as easy to read but it is genius!